# can you set one pointer to another pointer whose value is NULL

Tags: c++, pointers

if I have a pointer `a = null;`
and I initialize another pointer lets say `int * b;`

if I set `b = a`, will this simply give me `b = null`?

or will this give me a compiling error?

I know its a simple question, but I wanted to double check my understanding

Comment: Maybe you could try it?

Comment: `null` and `NULL` are two different identifiers, and `null` is not defined in C unless you define it yourself. Did you mean `NULL`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int *a = NULL
int *b = a;
```

Sure that code compiles and works fine. The pointer `b` gets a value of `NULL`, the same as `a`.

Just a note, when you refer to the null pointer in the code, it's `NULL` or `0`, not `null`.  Or better, use `nullptr` in C++11.

Comment: `nullptr` is a keyword by itself, so `std::` qualification is wrong (`nullptr`, but `std::nullptr_t`)

Answer (score 0):

null is the value of a, by doing b = a, b will take the value of a, null.

So no error. It's when you dereference pointers (using the *) that problems can occur, if the address (the value of the pointer) isn't valid.